# When i select all checkbox and trying to increase the record my checkbox selection gone i want keep checkbox selected in angular js

Tags: angularjs, frontend

I dont have permission to use local storage, session, cookies without this how i can resolve this issue

$rootScope.userChecked = [];
$rootScope.checkedAll = false;

```
$scope.checkDropItem = function (response_number, selected) {
  if (selected) {
    $rootScope.userChecked.push(response_number);
  } else {
    var idx = $rootScope.userChecked.indexOf(response_number);
    $rootScope.userChecked.splice(idx, 1);
    $rootScope.checkedAll = true;
  }

};

$scope.checkAllDropItem = function (checked) {
  $rootScope.userChecked = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.data.request_list, function (dropValueReq) {
    angular.forEach(dropValueReq.responseList, function (dropValueRes) {
      dropValueRes.selected = checked;
    });
  });
  if (!checked) {
    $rootScope.userChecked = [];
  }
  
};
```

i have tryed with $rootScope . i dont have permission to use local storage cookies session storage

is there any State option
to create state and store data.

when we increse the recored it will reload

i want exact solution in anuglar js